# Adding footer/EXIF (binary data) to JPG image in C#

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg, .net-4.5

Hello all I have an image and I want to add binary data as a footer to that image.

```
RGBImage rgbImage =  (RGBImage) RGBImage.LoadImage(@"test.tiff");
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TEMP\gili.bin");
int padding =(int) Math.Ceiling((double)bytes.Length/(rgbImage.Width*3));
byte[] newMakerNoteImage = new byte[rgbImage[0].Data.Length + (rgbImage.Width * 3 * padding)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(rgbImage[0].Data, 0, newMakerNoteImage, 0, rgbImage[0].Data.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, newMakerNoteImage, rgbImage[0].Data.Length, bytes.Length);

BitmapPalette myPalette = BitmapPalettes.WebPalette;

           // Creates a new empty image with the pre-defined palette
           BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
               rgbImage.Width,
               rgbImage.Height,
               96,
               96,
               PixelFormats.Bgr24,
               myPalette,
               newMakerNoteImage,
               rgbImage.Width * 3);

           FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\TEMP\new.jpg", FileMode.Create);
           JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
           encoder.FlipHorizontal = false;
           encoder.FlipVertical = false;
           encoder.QualityLevel = 30;
           encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
           encoder.Save(stream);
```

the image outputs fine however the binary data is not added to the end of the image.
Can you tell me if I'm doing it correctly?

I think i might be looking at it all wrong and I need to use EXIF in order to add this makernote data into the image. the data shoudln't be visible to the user of the image.

Comment: I would expect `BitmapSource.Create` to only process relevant data, and `JpegBitmapEncoder.Save` converts it into a different format anyway, so I wouldn't be surprised if this doesn't work. Have you tried adding your custom data to the output stream after calling `JpegBitmapEncoder.Save`?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet i'm trying to figure this out, I think that I need to use something like EXIF, because the width and height define the image. and I don't want to include this binary(makernote) into the image i want it as a footer.

Comment: `JpegBitmapEncoder` has a `MetaData` property, maybe that's useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my tested solution for EXIF/MakerNote creation
As far as I have read 37500 is the makernote  hexdecimal tag inside EXIF.

http://nicholasarmstrong.com/2010/02/exif-quick-reference/

```
 public void CreateMakerNoteJpgImage(byte[] makerNoteArray, string path)
        {
            BitmapPalette myPalette = BitmapPalettes.WebPalette;

            // Creates a new empty image with the pre-defined palette
            BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
                Width,
                Height,
                96,
                96,
                PixelFormats.Bgr24,
                myPalette,
                _channels[0].Data,
                Width * 3);

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

            BitmapMetadata metadata = new BitmapMetadata("jpg");
            //adding makernote data into EXIF of the jpeg image
            metadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=37500}", makerNoteArray);

            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.FlipHorizontal = false;
            encoder.FlipVertical = false;
            encoder.QualityLevel = 30;
            BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(image, null, metadata, null);
            encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
            encoder.Save(stream);
        }
```